# Launch application using dial pad in android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to launch my application through dial pad.I am using the following code. For dial pad to launch application (in Broadcast receiver)

```
public class HiddenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
try{

               // Toast.makeText(context,"Number Dialed",1).show();

                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                    serviceIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(serviceIntent);



                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, ""+e.getMessage());
                }
```

While pressing key through dial pad I want to launch my main activity in which I used the following

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hidden_receiver); 

         //Intent call here
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         //text here
```

But when I press my code its dialed number disappear but neither dialer pad disappear nor MainActivity launches.
how can this issues be resolved?Help me out.....
Thanks.

Comment: When you call a number(say 1234), you have to launch your app. isn't that your need?

Comment: @Anjali you got solution for this?

Comment: Still Not....No one is working correctly.If u get any, must intimate me. @Pankaj

Comment: @anjali on dial pad i dont know but on outgoing call i know..

Comment: Please share.... @Pankaj.

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32761878/3758898

Comment: @PankajAndroid : can u pls share the code

Answer (score 5):

Use the `BroadcastReceiver` as follows:

```
public class MyOutgoingCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // Extract phone number reformatted by previous receivers
    String phoneNumber = getResultData();
    if (phoneNumber == null) {
      // No reformatted number, use the original
      phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

         if(phoneNumber.equals("1234")){ // DialedNumber checking.
        // My app will bring up, so cancel the broadcast
        setResultData(null);

        // Start my app
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("extra_phone", phoneNumber);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
         }

}

}
```

Don't forget to register this receiver in your manifest

```
    <receiver android:name="MyOutgoingCallHandler">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also, include the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Now, if you are ignoring the number checking in receiver, you'll get dialed number inside your MainActivity,

```
String phone=getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_phone");
    if(!phone.equals(null)){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phone, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Do one thing, Put a `Log` or `Toast` inside onReceive() and check if its working.

Comment: PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission saved my day

Comment: for new Android API (>=23) you have to request `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` permission at runtime