# How to open another activity, when dialpad call number "1234"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to hide my application, and when users call from `dialpad "1234"` start my application.

I use this code but get error when call `1234`

```
public class receiver extends  BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {

        String number = getResultData();   
        if (number!=null) {

            if(number.equals("1234")){

                Toast.makeText(context,"Gps konumunuz bekleniyor..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                setResultData(null);
                Intent newintent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                newintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(newintent);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your logcat error?

Comment: use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>` in your `manifest`..

Comment: @shweta_jain Please don't edit question if you don't have new things to add..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
public class MyOutgoingCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract phone number reformatted by previous receivers
        String phoneNumber = getResultData();
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            // No reformatted number, use the original
            phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        }

        if(phoneNumber.equals("1234")){ // DialedNumber checking.
            // My app will bring up, so cancel the broadcast
            setResultData(null);

            // Start my app
            Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("extra_phone", phoneNumber);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }    
    }
}
```

And refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950623/launch-application-using-dial-pad-in-android) for detail..

Comment: thank you for your answer this code is running :). but when I enter another number "5252" my app was stopped. How can I do it?