# Open Activity With Dial Code

Tags: android

I want to develop app that doesn't have icon launcher. The app will run alarmscheduler which triggered when app is installed or phone is rebooted.

The problem is how can I open the activity since the app doesn't have intent filter like below:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Is there a way to handle dial code such as *#*#4635*#*# to open the activity ?
or any other solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Question seems like duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950623/launch-application-using-dial-pad-in-android

Comment: I can only think of a service running in the background and maybe use Intent new call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two ways:

1) as answer by @KishuDroid

2) By define code in manifest

```
    public class MySecretCodeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

In manifest file

```
<receiver android:name=".MySecretCodeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
        <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="4635" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Note:**

In Second method you must have to dial  `*#*#your_code#*#*` and *dont need to press call button*

But in first method you can customise your prefix or postfix of code. For example `*#your_code#` or `**your_code##`. but *you need to press call button.*

Comment: This code is not working in my case .. can u provide an alternate solution.?

Comment: To downvoter, please comment here your problem/issue. We can also solve your problem. If this que/ans not fit with your issue that doesnt mean this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Broadcast Receiver...

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if(null == bundle)
                    return;

            String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",phonenumber);
            Log.i("OutgoingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());

            if(code.equals("#056700") {
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.yourActivity"));
```

And Your Android Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.varma.samples.detectcalls.receivers.OutgoingCallReceiver"> 
   <intent-filter> 
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
   </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Also, include the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

Comment: This code is not working in my case . Can u please help me out?

Comment: Use runtime permission if you are using marshmallo or higher version